# How to get nth child value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have following html:

```
 <div id="buildyourform">

    <div class="fieldwrapper" id="field1">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Co-Author Name" class="fieldname m-wrap medium">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Co-Author Affiliation/Organization" class="fieldtype m-wrap medium">
    </div>
    <div class="fieldwrapper" id="field2">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Co-Author Name" class="fieldname m-wrap medium">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Co-Author Affiliation/Organization" class="fieldtype m-wrap medium">
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to get value of input boxes from each of the div of buildyourform

```
<script>
    $('#buildyourform > div:nth-child(i) > input.fieldname').val()
</script>
```

I tried above code but it's not working please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `:eq()` like following.

```
var first = $('.fieldname:eq(0)').val()
var second = $('.fieldname:eq(1)').val()
```

Comment: I have to get value dynamically like this: $('#buildyourform > div:nth-child(' + i + ') > input.fieldname').val()

Comment: OK. You can get all values using `each()` like `$('#buildyourform .fieldname').each(function(){
        var value = this.value;
    })` @Paramjeet

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the JQuery Docs:

```
jQuery( ":nth-child(index/even/odd/equation)" )
```

The `:nth-child` selector will get parsed. If you use an index (integer) then it will return you **all** the elements of the set that are the nth child of their parent. So depending on the set it will **return 0-n elements**.

```
jQuery( ":eq(index)" )
```

The `:eq` selector expects an index (integer) and will return the element at the given index (in the set) and **only this one**.

**The big difference between** `:nth-child` **and** `:eq`:

The `:nth-child` selector will return all elements (of the set) that are the nth child of their parent whereas `:eq` will return you only 1 element that is at the given index in the set!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this

`$(".fieldname:nth-child(1)")
$(".fieldname:nth-child(2)")`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what the OP meant, but this is how I would initially interpret the question he asked and I don't understand why jQuery (to my knowledge) doesn't provide something like this (tho maybe I'm just not familiar enough with jQuery)

```
function nth(element) {
    var parent = element.parentElement;
    if(element === parent || parent === null) return 0;
    else {
        var children = parent.getElementsByTagName(element.tagName);
        for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++) if(children[i] === element) return (i+1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script only get the value of the first input.
If you want to get the value of each input, you can use the $.each() function.

```
$('#buildyourform input').each(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I was trying my solution with nth child property of jquery but I got my answer using eq property:

```
$('#buildyourform > div:eq(' + (i-1) + ') > input.fieldname').val()
$('#buildyourform > div:eq(' + (i-1) + ') > input.fieldtype').val()
```

this code will run in for loop. where "i" is the value of for loop.